# Ошибка 400 Bad Request при использовании ajax в Wordpress

Tags: ajax, wordpress

Использование в Wordpress следующего кода возвращает ошибку 400 Bad Request. На экран выводится 0. В чём может быть причина?

Вот сам код:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_hello', 'say_hello');
function say_hello() {
    echo 'Привет пользователь!';
    wp-die();
}
```

Comment: Выложите код полностью, включая js. https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6688/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE-wordpress

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Почти наверняка у вас не определена `action` в ajax-запросе. В этом случае WordPress возвращает 400.

[Почитайте документацию](https://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html), и сделайте всё как положено, тогда не будет таких ошибок.